# use system icon in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I hope to use the MAC OS's icons at
http://oleb.net/wordpress/wp-content/media/apple-symbols-font-glyphs-table.png

how can I access these icons, export them from MAC system to png files or dynamically access them in cocoa codes ?

Welcome any commnent.

Thank

interdev

Comment: Before you go about doing this, you may wish to read the story of Rogue Amoeba's rejection from the App Store for using Mac icons: http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/iphone/ping/eff.php

Answer (score 1):

Before doing this, take Brad Larson's warning into account...

You'll need an image editor, like Photoshop or The Gimp that can handle glyph fonts.

Once you have that, you can use the Apple Symbols glyphs in a text field and save it as a transparent PNG, which you can then resize and add to your project as an icon.